# Channel race condition

Tags: go, concurrency, channel

This locks like a rather very basic problem regarding to channels. I have read that unbuffered channels block on send, so why this code has a race-condition?

Sometimes the output is

```
<- CREATE;
<- INSERT;
END
[CREATE; INSERT;]
```

Sometime the "INSERT;" is missing from the output, but it's written to the channel.

```
<- CREATE;
<- INSERT;
END
[CREATE; INSERT;]
```

How can the `SplitChan` func return, if it blocks on `cmd := <-c` from `Slit`?

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    batch := `CREATE;INSERT;`
    res := Split(batch)
    fmt.Print(res)
}

func SplitChan(batch string, outc chan<- string) {
    b := 0
    for i, c := range batch {
        switch c {
        case ';':
            cmd := batch[b : i+1]
            fmt.Println("<- " + cmd)
            b = i + 1
            outc <- cmd
        }
    }

    fmt.Println("END")
}

func Split(batch string) []string {
    var res []string
    c := make(chan string)
    go func() {
        for {
            cmd := <-c
            res = append(res, cmd)
        }
    }()

    SplitChan(batch, c)
    close(c)
    return res
}
```

Playground Link: https://go.dev/play/p/WmO5OtmgETl

I am expected the same output on every run:

```
<- CREATE;
<- INSERT;
END
[CREATE; INSERT;]
```

What am I missing here?
Thank you

Comment: There's a data race on `res`.  There's no guarantee that `res = append(res, cmd)` happens before `Split` returns.  Also, the goroutine spins in a tight loop after `close(c)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `SplitChan` writes to the channel, the append that's happening at the goroutine and the statement `return res` are concurrent. `return res` may see the slice with one element or two elements.

You have to make sure that before returning, the append operation is completed:

```
    wg:=sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        for cmd :=  range c {
            res = append(res, cmd)
        }
    }()

    SplitChan(batch, c)
    close(c)
    wg.Wait()
    return res
```

The WaitGroup ensures that the function returns after the goroutine is done.

Comment: Shouldn't wg.Done() be elsewhere the function above is infinite for loop and will never return

Comment: Or use an `ok` when receiving on the channel to know it was closed. The goroutine can then be completed via a simple `return` if `ok` is false.

Comment: See the fixed answer